# Snap package command not working

Tags: python, snap

I created a snap package sourced from my github repo named ubuntunews. It compiled without any errors and installed it without errors either. However when I type in the command `ubuntunews` to run it, it gives me an error `bash: /usr/local/bin/ubuntunews: No such file or directory`  which is weird because the snap path is /snap/bin/ubuntunews. 
I think it's because I installed the ubuntunews as a regular package some time ago but I've uninstalled it now and removed the ubuntunews script from /usr/local/bin but the snap command still doesn't work and keeps on displaying the same error. How do I go around that, this is my first experience with building snap packages.

```
name: ubuntunews 
version: '1.0' 
summary: Get latest news from omgubuntu website 
description: | 
  Webcraped omgubuntu website to get the latest news about your favourite 
  linux distro and it's flavours. 

grade: devel 
confinement: devmode 

apps: 
  ubuntunews: 
    command: bin/ubuntunews 
    plugs: [network] 

parts: 
  ubuntu-news: 
    source: https://github.com/Abugbilla/ubuntunews 
    source-type: git 
    plugin: python 
    python-version: python3 
    python-packages: [bs4]
```

Comment: Can you paste your `snapcraft.yaml` in your post please?

Comment: `name: ubuntunews
version: '1.0'
summary: Get latest news from omgubuntu website
description: |
  Webcraped omgubuntu website to get the latest news about your favourite 
  linux distro and it's flavours.
grade: devel 
confinement: devmode 

apps:
  ubuntunews:
    command: bin/ubuntunews
    plugs: [network]

parts:
  ubuntu-news:
    source: https://github.com/Abugbilla/ubuntunews
    source-type: git
    plugin: python
    python-version: python3
    python-packages: [bs4]`

Answer (score 1):

@popey I did that  and I was still getting the error. But I later found out that the issue was from the two conflicting paths for ubuntnews which are- /usr/local/bin/ubuntunews and /snap/bin/ubuntunews. To clear that I run `source ~./bashrc`  so that I could only get /snap/bin/ubuntunews which is the path I actually wanted. But now I'm getting a new error 
`/snap/ubuntunews/x1/usr/bin/python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /snap/ubuntunews/x1/usr/bin/python3)`

Answer (score 0):

It works and builds for me, but you're missing some dependencies. Perhaps you're missing `python-gi`.

```
alan@hal:~/tmp/ubuntunews⟫ snap install ubuntunews_1.0_amd64.snap --dangerous --devmode
ubuntunews 1.0 installed
alan@hal:~/tmp/ubuntunews⟫ snap run ubuntunews
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/ubuntunews/x1/bin/ubuntunews", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ubuntunews==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'ubuntunews')()
  File "/snap/ubuntunews/x1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/snap/ubuntunews/x1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2755, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/snap/ubuntunews/x1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2408, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/snap/ubuntunews/x1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2414, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/snap/ubuntunews/x1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ubuntunews/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import brain
  File "/snap/ubuntunews/x1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ubuntunews/brain.py", line 12, in <module>
    import gi
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
```

So I'd imagine you need at least:-

```
stage-packages:
  - python3-gi
```